# Why System.Xml doesn't contain XmlDocument in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I cannot find this class in silverlight and searching the internet has been clueless. So what's the equivalent of this class in silverlight ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) ->
[Example](http://thibautvs.com/blog/?p=851)

```
XDocument xmlStories = XDocument.Parse("</a>");
// or
XDocument xmlStories = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

Based on searches it appears Microsoft wanted a more LINQ friendly implementation which is XDocument.

Comment: Naked links don't make for useful answers. Can you add a summary of why you think the page you link to is an answer.

Comment: @ChrisF He asked for the equivalent class in silverlight. A single class name answer is very appropriate and I even included an example blog.

Comment: You should explain that in the answer - much better and possibly even worth an upvote.

Comment: I hate when they want to force people to use linq :( :) @Andrew thanks for the link very usefull.